# Can I use .Net languages for iPhone app development?

Tags: c#, iphone, .net

I am interested in iPhone app development.  Are there any products or platforms that allow iPhone application development using .NET languages, such as C#?

Answer (score 12):

The [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) team, formerly employees from Novell working on the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) project, have developed cross-platform compilers and runtimes for both [iOS](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) and [Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

While it doesn't yet create a "write-once run anywhere" utopia of mobile application development, it's definitely a step in the right direction and perhaps better than HTML5 solutions.

I've found it best to write core libraries (just the app logic, no UI code) that compiles under .NET and Mono.  Then, write UI layers specific to each platform you want to support.  Using an MVC pattern, you can abstract things in such a way that makes code very re-usable.

Answer (score 5):

There are two platforms called **MonoTouch** and **Mono** through which you can develop iOS app using C# and .NET.

1. **[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)**
2. **[MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)**

I'll suggest this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024002.do) for you to learn mobile development in C#.

---

If you are interested in **HTML** and **javascript** the following sdk's will help you.

1. [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/)
2. [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)
3. [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)